# ADF Mapping Data in Sink Table Error - Sink Table remains empty

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Data flow in Azure Data Factory which I want to use to combine data from three sources and then sink in a destination table (with some transformation in-between). For the sink table I created a table in SQL, matching the column headers and data types from my Data Flow in Azure.

However when I publish the data flow, the sink table remains empty. The only error I get is under Mapping "At least one incoming column is mapped to a column in the sink dataset schema with a conflicting type, which can cause NULL values or runtime errors." This seems to be inhibiting me from enabling Auto Mapping - so I mapped the columns manually.

So where I'm at the moment:

DataFlowLayout

[image]

1. I tried manually mapping the columns - the datatypes in my input and my sink tables match up with each other but my sink table is still empty

SinkTableDataMapping

[image]

2. Under Data Preview for both my source and my sink tables I am able to view a sample of my data, so they are not empty

SinkTableDataPreview
[image]

Anyone experience something similar?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the Sink Mapping? Also, any chance the Dataset schema has changed? If so, it may need a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The details provided about is not sufficient to provide any inputs. Can you add more details like what are the file format of those three sources/from where you are pulling/ additional screenshots that will really help to guide better. Thanks

Comment: So the data sources are all in SQL format. In my sink table there are 68 <float> columns, one <date> column and one <varchar> column - in total 70 columns, which matches my dataflow output (also 70 columns with the same data formats for each column)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below steps:

**Disable auto mapping** of columns in Sink Transformation and manually map columns.

And check **Allow insert option** selected under sink transformation settings.

Also make sure all column data types of input and output of Sink transformation should match to avoid nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback. In the end the issue was that the pipeline which sinks the data from the flow, in the destination table was not properly set up - that is why the dataflow was not showing any errors but the sink table still remained empty. So the dataflow was kind of hanging in the air with no instruction to actually perform the sink